# VBA: Can't set a variable of a Structure within a class

Tags: excel, vba, interface, structure

I have a class, implementing two interfaces, one interface for normal use, and one interface that only reveals a function to create the class with initial parameters. The class has a field that is a Structure with two variables within, I am using the Get property of the class to get the structure, and then using dot notation to access the field within the structure, and then I am trying to set it to a number, but it never works. If I try to access the structure with the private variable within the class it works, but I want to be consistent and only use the properties to modify it within the `Create` function.

```
Public Function Create(WorksheetName As String, Optional CurrentRow As Long = 4) As ISheetInfo
    With New clsSheetInfo
        Set .WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(WorksheetName)
        Set .Cols = CreateColumnDictionary(.WS, 3)
        Let .Rows.Current = CurrentRow
        Let .Rows.Final = .WS.Cells(.WS.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Create = .Self
    End With
End Function
```

When I step through, it first goes to this property (`RowData` is the UDT with two fields, `.Current` and `.Final`:

```
Property Get Rows() As RowData
     Rows = pRows
End Property
```

But then after the assignment, `.Rows.Current` is still 0, I'm not sure why.

Comment: It returns a copy of your UDT. You'd need to expose a Let property to reassign the amended UDT.

Comment: @Rory, are you saying that whenever a `Property Get` is used, it creates a copy of the variable it is getting? Do you know where I could read up on this, I didn't see it in the documentation?

Comment: @Rory, I'm having trouble figuring out how I would get the Rows property, modify the field, and then reassign the updated Structure back to the variable, any ideas on this?

Comment: Assign it to a variable of the relevant UDT type, modify its elements, then assign that variable to the `Rows` property of the class instance.

Comment: @Rory, I'm also noticing in the watch window, that there is something wrong with my get property all together, it isn't getting the Structure variable, any idea why?

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by that?